# Android Sqlite Disk I/O error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I Have an app1 which has Sqlite db and exposes content provider to app2 and app3. If I uninstall and reinstall app1, on next launch of app1, I see Sqlite disk I/O exception.

But this won't happen if I uninstall app2 and app3 before uninstalling app1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the code for how you are declaring the Provider, including the Manifest

Comment: did you got the solution ? i am facing similar issue at my end